# Fileinput no detecta archivo inicializado con javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-file-input

Tengo una lista de imagenes que tienen un titulo. Para editar el registro, en la tabla se agrego un icono de un lapiz que tiene como propiedades data el titulo y la ruta de la imagen. Esto para que al iniciliar el input de mi formulario editar gargue la imagen y el titulo.

Este es mi codigo JS que obtiene los atributos data y los pone en el formulario editar:

```
$(document).on("click", ".ti-pencil", function() {
var imagen = $(this).data('imagen')
var titulo = $(this).data('titulo')
var id = $(this).data('id')
$("#editar input[name='id']").val(id)
$("#editar input[name='titulo']").val(fromHTML(titulo))
$("#editar input[type='file']").fileinput('destroy')
$("#editar input[name='imagen']").fileinput({
    language: 'es',
    autoOrientImage: true,
    browseClass: "btn btn-primary btn-block",
    allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'webp' ,'jpeg'],
    initialPreviewAsData: true,
    initialPreviewFileType: 'image',
    overwriteInitial: false,
    uploadAsync: false,
    removeIcon: "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i>",
    initialPreview: "../../images/slider/"+imagen,
})
$("#nuevo").hide()
$("#editar").show()
})
```

Cuando solo edito el titulo o no edito nada y solo lo guardo no me reconoce que se tenga una imagen cargada en mi input file, como se ve en la iamgen de abajo. He inicializado el archivo como indica la documentacion pero aun no me ha dado resultado.

[image: Error al enviar el formulario]

[image: Archivos requeridos para usar fileinput]

Comment: No se entiende tu problema